# JavaScript RegExp: What am I replacing?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a JavaScript syntax highlighter, that I need for a project I'm starting later.

I have an expression called keywords.

```
var keywords = /break|case|catch|default|delete|do|else|false|for|function|if|in|instanceof|new|null|prototype|return|switch|throw|this|true|try|typeof|var|while|with/g
```

I then run `script.replace(keywords, "<keyword>" + /* I have no idea what to put here. */ + "</keyword>");`

How can I tell what it's replacing, so I can insert the keyword in between the tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can do this:

```
var keywords = /break|case|catch|default|delete|do|else|false|for|function|if|in|instanceof|new|null|prototype|return|switch|throw|this|true|try|typeof|var|while|with/g;
var script = 'return 1';
script.replace(keywords, "<keyword>$&</keyword>");
```

That is, in this simple case, you don't need to use capturing parentheses. The special token: `$&` returns the text matched by the whole regex. (In other languages, this is frequently specified as: `$0` - i.e. capture group *zero*.) There are several special tokens you can use in a Javascript string.replace string:

```
    $1, $2, $3,...$99  The text matching capture groups 1-99.
    $&                 The substring that matched the whole regex.
    $`                 The text to the left of the matched substring.
    $'                 The text to the right of the matched substring.
    $$                 A literal dollar sign
```

This is taken from: "Javascript: the Definitive Guide (5th Edition)", by David Flanagan. This excellent Javascript reference is highly recommended (and there is a [new revision about to come out](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805527) too - Yay!)

And regarding Javascript syntax highlighting... I've been looking into this lately and can make a couple recommendations:
* The most popular is [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). However, I recently discovered a nasty bug at its very core and wrote an article about it: [Fixing the SyntaxHighlighter 3.0.83 Parser Bug](http://jmrware.com/articles/2011/sh-bug/SyntaxHighlighterBug.html)
* Also, take a look at the [McLexer/McHighlighter](http://matt.might.net/articles/lexing-and-syntax-highlighting-in-javascript/) by Matt Might. (This guy is wicked smart). Although this one also has a bug when you run it under Opera. (this bug is easily fixed by removing the line which explicitly compiles the regex.)
* Also, take a look at Google prettify (which is used by this site if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: I'm a homebrew kind of guy. I prefer to build everything myself. I even wrote my own jQuery. xD

Comment: @tylermwashburn - So am I. But take a look at Matt's code. It is quite short (but very dense - at least it was for me.) I learned a lot. Also take a look at the specialized javascript syntax highlighter I wrote which dynamically highlights the structure of regular expressions. See: [Dynamic (?:Regex Highlighting)++ with Javascript!](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/dynregexhl/DynamicRegexHighlighter.html)

Comment: Just a note about Matt Might, he works at the same university as my uncle. I might just try to meet him. :)

Comment: I just noticed that you live in Salt Lake too. Do you know Matt personally?

Comment: Not yet. But I recently had an email exchange with him regarding some questions about his code. Hey, I just got my first answer - WooHoo! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you wrap your pattern in parenthesis, then the regex will capture it for you to use in your replacement pattern. In this case, you can do:

```
var keywords = /(break|case|catch|default|delete|do|else|false|for|function|if|in|instanceof|new|null|prototype|return|switch|throw|this|true|try|typeof|var|while|with)/g;
var script = 'return 1';
script.replace(keywords, "<keyword>$1</keyword>");
```

Each pattern that you capture is available in the replacement pattern as `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.

Comment: Nathan, you beat me to it.  Here's a helpful page on regular expressions that explains how to use the capturing parends  http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html